# Plot error doing genetics: Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: r, matrix, plot, genetics

was trying to plot to visualize transition probabilities using some functions for the legend and I get the error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Don't know where I messed up but here is my whole code:

```
#here I construct probability matrices
N<-1
possible<-0:(2*N)

P<-NULL#vector para contener nuestras probabilidades
for(i in possible){
  P<-c(P,dbinom(possible, size=2*N, prob=i/(2*N)))
}
(Q<-matrix(P,ncol=2*N+1, byrow=T))

(x<-matrix(c(rep(0,2*N+1)), ncol=2*N+1, byrow=T))

x[,2]<-1
x

(R<-x%*%Q)

color <- c("brown","blue","grey")
shape <- c(15,19,17)

#then here comes the plot part that gives me the error
g <- rep(1,ncol(R))

plot(points(x=NULL, xlim=c(1,10), ylim=c(0,1),
              ylab="Probability",
              xlab="Generations"))
legend("bottomleft",
       legend=c("Extinct", "One copy","Fixed"),
       col=color, pch=shape,
       xpd=TRUE, inset=c(0,1),bty="n")
while(g[1]<=10){
  (R <- R%*%Q)
  g <- g+1
  points(g, R, col=color, pch=shape)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming to create a blank plot I would remove `points` so you should have the following (Note: you can also use `type="n"` to create a blank plot):

```
plot(x=NULL, xlim=c(1,10), ylim=c(0,1),
              ylab="Probability",
              xlab="Generations")
```

Output:

[image]

Using the rest of your code you get the following:

```
#here I construct probability matrices
N<-1
possible<-0:(2*N)

P<-NULL#vector para contener nuestras probabilidades
for(i in possible){
  P<-c(P,dbinom(possible, size=2*N, prob=i/(2*N)))
}
(Q<-matrix(P,ncol=2*N+1, byrow=T))

(x<-matrix(c(rep(0,2*N+1)), ncol=2*N+1, byrow=T))

x[,2]<-1
x

(R<-x%*%Q)

color <- c("brown","blue","grey")
shape <- c(15,19,17)

#then here comes the plot part that gives me the error
g <- rep(1,ncol(R))

plot(x=NULL, xlim=c(1,10), ylim=c(0,1),
              ylab="Probability",
              xlab="Generations")
legend("bottomleft",
       legend=c("Extinct", "One copy","Fixed"),
       col=color, pch=shape,
       xpd=TRUE, inset=c(0,1),bty="n")
while(g[1]<=10){
  (R <- R%*%Q)
  g <- g+1
  points(g, R, col=color, pch=shape)
}
```

[image]